# Is there an IDE or vim plugin or whatever that can auto complete member function in writing the code?

Tags: c++, vim, ide

In C++, say I have file ABC.hpp, and ABC.cpp. In ABC.hpp, we write a number of constructors and member functions:

```
ABC();
ABC(blahblah);
~ABC();

int memberFunc1();
int memberFunc2();
int memberFunc3();
int memberFunc4();
...
```

Is there an IDE or something that can automatically generate lines of code in corresponding ABC.cpp file something like this:

```
ABC::ABC();
ABC::ABC(blahblah);
ABC::~ABC();

int ABC::memberFunc1();
int ABC::memberFunc2();
int ABC::memberFunc3();
int ABC::memberFunc4();
...
```

Or even better, it can check if a member function hasn't been implemented, and gives a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged this with `vim`, probably [YouCompleteMe](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

QtCreator can write the method stub, just right click on the header's method definition, Refactor -> Add Definition in ABC.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Visual Studio, you can use `Visual Assist` + `ViEmu`. If you're using vim on Linux, `YouCompleteMe` or `onmicppcomplete` or `onmicppcompletecache` maybe be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CLION (Jetbrains)](http://www.jetbrains.com/clion). You will love it